# Export google drive file in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, google-drive-api, export

I want to export google drive file, but I don't know type of file before. I used drive.files.export but it requires mimeType which I don't know. mimeType from drive.files.get can't be used in export. How can I download file if I only have file id?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You don't know in which mimeType you want to export the file? Also, is it a G Suite document?

Comment: I don't know what type of file it is going to be because user has an option to choose file. But I managed to fix it. It seems that mimeType 'application/vnd.google-apps.document' can't be used for export but 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether the file is a G Suite document, the downloading process you should follow is different.

If the file is [a G Suite document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_google_document), you have to use [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) and specify which mimeType you want to export your file to. [See here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats) for a reference of the different Google documents and the supported export MIME types. If you want to export your file to different MIME types depending on which type it is in Drive, you can first do [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) and, based on which mimeType the file is and based on the referenced table, export it in a corresponding type. For example, if your file's MIME type is `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`, you may want to export it to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

If the file is not a G Suite document, you have to use [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to download and set the parameter `alt` to `media`, as explained [in the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads). Here is a code snippet corresponding to doing this in Node.js, as specified there:

```js
var fileId = 'your-file-id';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/photo.jpg');
drive.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media'
})
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
```

So, summing this up, what I would do is, first, get the mimeType of the file you want to export, via `files.get`, and based on this mimeType (depending on whether the file is a G Suite document and which type of document), download the file one way or another.

#### Reference:

- [Manage downloads in Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)
- [G Suite documents and corresponding export MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks. I was using this way but as I said in previous comment, some mimeType can't be used in export. But thanks anyways.